# variable expansion inside namespace-qualified variable name

Tags: powershell, variables, expansion

#### Problem

I want to perform parametric variable evaluation. The to-be-evaluated variable name is constructed with a string concatenation - from a *namespace* part and a *name* part being defined in a variable. Example: `env:$var`, where the value of `$var` is,   for instance `"OS"`. However, while using the expression

```
${env:OS}
```

gives the expected value `Windows_NT`, the construct

```
$var="OS"
${env:$var}
```

is a null-valued expression.

#### Motivation

I'm not really intereseted in the value of environment variables (but this was the simplest example, I could find). What I really want, is to refer to the content of a file via the `${c:<filename>}` construct. I want to perform several, conditional in-file string substitutions and, I'd like to use a construct similar to this:

```
<identify files in a foreach>
${c:<filename>} -replace 'this', 'that' > ${c:<new filename>}
```

To achieve this, I need `<filename>` to be a value of an iterator variable.

#### Question

If the value of `$var` is `OS`, what shall be at `...`, if I expect the value of the following expression to be `Windows_NT`?

```
${env:...var...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` on the `env:` PSDrive and expand the `Value` of the result:

```
(ls env:$var).Value
```

**Edit:** As @PetSerAl suggested in the comments using `Get-Content` is a more elegant approach:

```
(cat env:$var)
```

Comment: I would use `Get-Content` instead of `Get-ChildItem`: `gc env:$var`.

Comment: Thanks, at last, I've decided to use the `(gc env:$var)` form.